Opening popup window on different monitor in Chrome
I can't believe the hassle I'm having trying to do this. What I need to do, is open up 12 popups on my PC - all opening a different page. Currently, I'm having to manually move 2 of them onto each screen every day. I want to be able to click my button, and programmatically move / set their location onto a different screen. I have 6 screens, all the same size. I found so many posts, and quite a few going back over 10 years:
`window.open` on the second monitor in Chrome
Surely this is possible? I have tried manually setting negative top/left, but all it does is move the position on the primary screen. I'm on Windows 11, using the latest Chrome (happy to move to Firefox if it helps!).

If the pages you open allow themselves to be open in an iFrame, you can open them all in one new window so you only have to move it once

Modern browsers do not provide a built-in way to control the position of a new window on a screen other than the primary one. The window.open method in JavaScript allows you to specify the top and left properties, but these are relative to the primary screen only.
